# Angular Router Resolve function not working

Tags: angular, angular-router-params

```
// user-resolver.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { User } from 'firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable()
export class UserResolver implements Resolve<User> {
  constructor(private _firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<User> {
    return this._firebaseAuth.authState;
  };
}

//app-routing.module.ts 

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UserResolver } from './services/user-resolver.service';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { AuthGuardService as AuthGuard } from './services/auth-guard.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'user', component: UserComponent, resolve: { user: UserResolver }, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [UserResolver],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Can't navigate to the UserComponent Page. If I were to remove the resolve property from the routes then it works. But when trying to resolve the user it doesn't works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see you using the resolver in any of the routes.

Comment: I am using it. Let me update the code snippet.

Comment: Don't know firebase, but your issues seems like `this._firebaseAuth.authState` is never returning a response, did you check that?

Comment: Either that or it's returning something equivalent to false, hence the resolver not allowing the navigation.

Comment: It does return an observable.

Comment: I have the same problem, others solution seems working when using "children" in routes, but not when using `RouterModule.forRoot`